# django if a record has some self foreign key value, then operate on the foreign key record

Tags: django

In order to avoid changing a lot of existing code, I try to add a self foreign key to a model, then the operations(filter,get,update,save,...) on the record will automatically performed on the "real record" if it has the self foreign key value.what need I do?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=50)
    real_one = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
```

I am expecting:

```
tom = Person.objects.create(name='Tom') # id=1
Person.objects.create(name='someone', real_one=tom) # id=2

someone = Person.objects.filter(name='someone')[0]
print someone.id # 1
print someone.name # Tom
someone.name = 'Jack'
someone.save()
tom = Person.objects.filter(name='Tom')[0] # sorry, this line added late
print tom.name # 'Jack'
```

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question -- its a bit unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: He's implementing aliasing: a `Person` is a real person if `real_one` is `None`. If `real_one` is not `None`, it's an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you're trying to do this in a denormalized fashion and it probably isn't going to work for you. One thing you could do is:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=50)
    real_one = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

    @property
    def real_name(self):
        if(self.real_one):
            return self.real_one.real_name
        else:
            return self.real_name

    @real_name.setter
    def real_name_setter(self, val):
        if(self.real_one):
            self.real_one.real_name = val
            self.real_one.save()
        else:
            self.real_name = val
            self.save()
```

but this creates a lot of database transactions. Note also the *required* side effect of the setter, since it has to save the record immediately lest it lose track of which record was changed. And this still has a problem in that the following case won't work:

```
someone.name = 'Jack'
someone.save()
print tom.name # 'Tom' <-- The 'tom' object now has stale data!
```

One object is being changed, yet (as far as Python is concerned) an *entirely different* object is really being changed. There's no reliable way to do this without changing Django and creating a mess (Django would have to internally track every object that referred to a given record, which plays havoc with the garbage collector, Django's queryset lazy-evaluation generators, and maybe even transactions).

Your best bet is to try a different approach, or live with the fact that your example isn't going to work. If you stick with this schema, every `filter` and `exclude` queryset call, and probably others, is going to need to know about this aliasing.

IMHO, you're much, much better off changing the schema: one table with names and one table with the "real" info for each person. The name table has foreign keys to the info table.

If you're trying to do something else, then you need to explain *what* a lot clearer in the question.